# How do I prevent two ansible jobs to run against the same machine?

Tags: ansible

In order to avoid surprises I want to implement a solution that prevent concurrent deployment towards the same target host.

Please remember that we do not want to obstruct the ability to deploy from our own machines instead of a centralised admin server.

We just want to assure that we are not doing the same thing in parallel.

Comment: How can this be not a closed question when synchronized access is one of the most complicated programming topics in multitask environments

Answer (score 4):

You could check for a file and drop a file on the host you execute against:

```
 tasks:    
   - stat: path=.ansible_lock_file
     register: lock_file_check

   - fail: msg="ansible is already being run against this host"
     when: lock_file_check.stat.exists

   - file: path=.ansible_lock_file state=touch`
```

And remove it at the end of your playbook

```
   - file: path=.ansible_lock_file state=touch
```

Comment: Good start but it lacks one key part: fails miserably if the playbook fails to run completely. Also, it would be very helpful to be able to implement it all playbook without having to duplicate code.

Comment: You can use handlers to prevent it from hanging around and use an include file to make it reusable across playbooks.

Comment: You can use the new rescue method in Ansible 2.0 for that: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_blocks.html#error-handling

Answer (score 1):

While not yet a full answer, my impression is that the elegant solution is to write a callback plugin that implements that.

Still, I am not sure if the callback API allows me to inject some additional tasks to run, to access ansible variables or to abort the play in some conditions.

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/osx_say.py

Answer (score 0):

While a lock file is a technical solution, I'd like to instead propose a cultural one: a vocalized "deploy lock".

Many development teams have an internal chat channel where they coordinate releases; a bot displays the status of any currently-ongoing releases, and the developers mention when they're getting ready to deploy something.  Sometimes, this is formalized a bit, with the bot also keeping track of who has the lock, or even maintaining a queue of people in line for the lock.

You can do the same thing with your operations team.  It's a bit easier than relying on the code you've written to be correct, and more importantly, it helps keep everyone on the same page - and for more chat systems, automatically provides a log of what changed when.

Comment: We already implemented that for some deployments but this does not work for CD ones. imagine that almost every change triggers a deployment to test environment, this can happen even 10 times an hour. So, we ended up vocalising (via ansible slack module) only some of the deployment jobs.

Comment: What if an ansible script is triggered automatically. There should be zero discussion that we need a technical solution. Especially if the solution is so simple and well known flock and the problem the tool

Comment: @Lothar If you have situations where scripts are triggered automatically, then you probably want a lockfile.  Not everyone does.

Comment: I'll mention additionally though that even many "automatic trigger" situations are still actually manually triggered.  For instance, "run on merge" setups only trigger when commits are merged into a branch, and most of that time that's something done by a human - so you can shift your social lock to gate merging.  As always, you'll have to evaluate your own situation and decide what makes the most sense there.

Comment: Lockfiles without atomic locks are unsafe and add extra really bad maintenance cases. And for use cases, don't think developer, think admin and automatisation. I have a script that pulls in contents from other sources every x-minutes. Or what about backups?